# Combining probabilities together

Tags: probability

I'd like to understand how I can combine probability

For example, lets say a train driver gets mesaured on their performance with Yellow card per month. If the driver gets Yellow card for 12 consecutive months, the driver will be sacked.

If we say the probability of driver getting a yellow card due to violating rule A is 0.4 per month, rule B is 0.3 per month and rule C is 0.7 per month.

I can easily calculate the probability of the driver getting sacked because of rule C is **0.7^12=0.0138**

However I'm confused on how I can work out the probability of the driver getting sacked because of all the rules A,B and C? The confusion comes from whether I can simply add the probabilities together because if I combine them all it becomes larger than 1 which doesn't make sense.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer.  You need to find $P(A\cup B\cup C)$ which expands via inclusion-exclusion as $P(A) +P(B)+P(C) - P(AB) - P(AC) - P(BC) + P(ABC)$.  "Just adding" like you tried to do only works if they can't occur simultaneously which by the fact they add to greater than 1 implies can't be the case.  And before you suggest that you can break it apart with multiplication that is only valid if the events are independent which is not a valid assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of getting at least one yellow card in a given month is one minus the probability of getting no yellow cards.

$P(\ge 1) = 1 - (0.6\cdot 0.7\cdot 0.3) = 1 - .126 = .874$

The probability of getting $12$ consecutive months of at least one yellow card  is therefore

$P(\ge 1\ \text{per month}) = .874^{12} = .19867$

Comment: Thanks very much. I used ur formula and the one from @JMoravitz both give me the same answer :)